# Condition in thread doesn't work in Android App

Tags: java, android, timer

I have a mobile game app. The game gives a random number (for example 20) with 16 buttons (random numbers don't equal to 20) along with 4 buttons (mathematical operators (+,-,/, and *)). The user should perform any number of calculations to get the number 20.

In this game, there is a timer starts from 350 and after each second, this timer will decrease by one. Also, there is a score, whenever the player gets the exact answer this score will increase by one and will start a new activity for the same game and use the bundle to send the score and timer to the new activity.

In the thread, there is a condition (if the timer becomes -1 go to a new activity (End of the game activity)), In the end of the game activity, there is a replay button, if the player clicks it, it starts a new activity (new game). The problem occurs here, in this game the timer decrease so fast and doesn't stop even if the timer becomes -1. I have no idea why this happens? What is the problem?

Game.java

```js
package reemaljunaid.mathmatch;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * Created by Reem on 12/28/2016.
 */

public class Game extends AppCompatActivity {
    Thread t;
    static int scoreNumber = 0;
    static int operation = 0;
    static boolean flag = true;
    Set<Integer> RandomNumberList = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
    static Button button11, button12, button13, button14,
            button21, button22, button23, button24,
            button31, button32, button33, button34,
            add, sub, mult, div;
    static ImageView clear ;
    static TextView result, score, time, number;
    static boolean selected = true;
    static String username;


    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        this.stopService(new Intent(this, MusicService.class));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onPause();
        this.startService(new Intent(this, MusicService.class));
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
        super.onPause();
        this.stopService(new Intent(this, MusicService.class));
    }
    Intent music;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game);
        Intent music = new Intent();
        music.setClass(this,MusicService.class);
        startService(music);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        username = intent.getStringExtra("username");

        selected = true;
        button11 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button11);
        button12 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button12);
        button13 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button13);
        button14 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button14);

        button21 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button21);
        button22 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button22);
        button23 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button23);
        button24 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button24);

        button31 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button31);
        button32 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button32);
        button33 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button33);
        button34 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button34);


        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
        sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sub);
        mult = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mult);
        div = (Button) findViewById(R.id.div);

        clear = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.clear);
        result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
        score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
        time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);
        number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number);


        operation = 0;

        Update ();
        String timer = intent.getStringExtra("time");
        if(timer != null)
            time.setText(timer);
        else{
            time.setText("350");
        }
        int scoreNumber = intent.getIntExtra("score",0);
        if(scoreNumber != 0)
        {score.setText(String.valueOf(scoreNumber));}



        clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                result.setText("0");
                selected=true;
                operation = 0;
            }
        });
        button11.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setResult(button11);
            }
        });

        button12.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setResult(button12);
            }
        });

        button13.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setResult(button13);
            }
        });

        button14.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setResult(button14);
            }
        });

        button21.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setResult(button21);
            }
        });

        button22.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setResult(button22);
            }
        });

        button23.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setResult(button23);
            }
        });

        button24.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setResult(button24);
            }
        });

        button31.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setResult(button31);
            }
        });

        button32.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setResult(button32);
            }
        });

        button33.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setResult(button33);
            }
        });

        button34.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setResult(button34);
            }
        });

        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                operation = 1;
                selected = true;
            }
        });

        sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                operation = 2;
                selected = true;

            }
        });

        mult.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                operation = 3;
                selected = true;

            }
        });

        div.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                operation = 4;
                selected = true;

            }
        });

       t = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (!isInterrupted()) {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                               int curTime = Integer.parseInt(time.getText().toString()) - 1;
                                if(curTime==-1 && flag){
                                    Log.d("Thread Username :",""+username);
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(Game.this, End.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("score",score.getText().toString());
                                    intent.putExtra("username",username);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    flag = false;
                                }
                                else{
                                    time.setText(String.valueOf(curTime));}

                            }
                        });
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        };

        t.start();



    }

    protected void Update () {

        Random rng = new Random();
        while (RandomNumberList.size() < 13)
        {
            Integer next = rng.nextInt(40) + 1;
            RandomNumberList.add(next);
        }
        List<Integer> RandomNumberList1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(RandomNumberList);
        number.setText(String.valueOf(RandomNumberList1.get(12)));
        button11.setText(String.valueOf(RandomNumberList1.get(0)));
        button12.setText(String.valueOf(RandomNumberList1.get(1)));
        button13.setText(String.valueOf(RandomNumberList1.get(2)));
        button14.setText(String.valueOf(RandomNumberList1.get(3)));
        button21.setText(String.valueOf(RandomNumberList1.get(4)));
        button22.setText(String.valueOf(RandomNumberList1.get(5)));
        button23.setText(String.valueOf(RandomNumberList1.get(6)));
        button24.setText(String.valueOf(RandomNumberList1.get(7)));
        button31.setText(String.valueOf(RandomNumberList1.get(8)));
        button32.setText(String.valueOf(RandomNumberList1.get(9)));
        button33.setText(String.valueOf(RandomNumberList1.get(10)));
        button34.setText(String.valueOf(RandomNumberList1.get(11)));

    }

    protected void add (int x, int y){
        int z = x+y;
        result.setText(String.valueOf(z));
        selected  = false;
        checkAnswer (z);
    }
    protected void sub (int x, int y){
        int z = x-y;
        result.setText(String.valueOf(z));
        selected  = false;
        checkAnswer (z);
    }
    protected void mult (int x, int y){
        int z = x*y;
        result.setText(String.valueOf(z));
        selected  = false;
        checkAnswer (z);
    }
    protected void div (int x, int y){
        int z = x/y;
        result.setText(String.valueOf(z));
        selected  = false;
        checkAnswer (z);
    }

    protected void setResult(Button button){
        if (selected){
            int num1 = Integer.parseInt(result.getText().toString());
            int num2 = Integer.parseInt(button.getText().toString());

            if (operation == 0)
            {result.setText(button.getText());}
            else if (operation == 1)
            {
                add(num1,num2);

            }
            else if (operation == 2)
            {
                sub(num1,num2);
            }
            else if (operation == 3)
            {
                mult(num1,num2);
            }
            else if (operation == 4)
            {
                div(num1,num2);
            }
            selected = false;

        }
        else{
        }

    }

    protected void checkAnswer (int x){
        int answer = Integer.valueOf(number.getText().toString());
        if (answer == x){
            Toast.makeText(Game.this,"Good Jop!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            scoreNumber+=10;
            Log.d("Check Game Username : ",""+username);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Game.this, Game.class);
            intent.putExtra("time",time.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("score",scoreNumber);
            intent.putExtra("username",username);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        }
    }

}
```

End.java

```js
package reemaljunaid.mathmatch;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.icu.text.DateFormat;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Created by Reem on 1/2/2017.
 */

public class End extends AppCompatActivity {

    static String username;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.end);
        final TextView scoreResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scoreResult);
        final TextView bestScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bestScore);
        final Button back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
        final Button replay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.replay);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String score = intent.getStringExtra("score");
        username = intent.getStringExtra("username");
        Log.d("End Game Username : ",""+username);

        scoreResult.setText(score);
        MainDB db = new MainDB(this);
        String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        db.insertGame (username,currentDateTimeString,score, "0");
        final Cursor cursor =  db.getBestScoreForUser(username);
        if (cursor.moveToNext())
        {
            bestScore.setText(cursor.getString(0));
        }

        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(End.this, MainMenu.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        replay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(End.this, Game.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: just use countDownTImer.. it will be very simple.

Comment: Have you interrupted the Thread once the game ended? So that you close it, once the game is over and re-initialize it again on "Replay button". Might be that your Thread is still running in background, even though game ended?

Comment: Prashanth Debbadwar I tried this it's really way better and easier, thank you.

Comment: DavidK I tried to interrupt all these threads, but the problem still exists